# Can you query SQL Server directly from the Entity Framework Designer?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

When you're inside Visual Studio you can use the Server Explorer to add a Data Connection.  Once you've added the data connection you can browse the schema, execute queries, etc.

Another developer mentioned that EF might have this functionality.  With the EF designer, you would already have a connection setup and even have the list of tables mapped as well.  It would be great to right click on a model in the designer and view the data, or execute queries.

This would allow a user to open a solution and instantly (well almost) view the data being used, whereas right now you would need to add the connection to the Server Explorer (again).

Does anything like this exist, either in Visual Studio, NuGet Package, Service Pack, Tools Update, or even an extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in Visual Studio but as separate tool called [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/EntityFramework.aspx).

Edit:

If you create EDMX model through the Wizard it will create connection for you in Server explorer but this connection is VS feature. It has nothing to do with Entity designer which works just with connection string.

Comment: Yeah, but then you have to re-add connections, which is what I was trying to avoid.  I don't necessarily need to query the DB with LINQ, SQL is fine too.

Comment: I didn't realize that about the Wizard... but I didn't have a connection to my server after making my model... Maybe something to do with the fact that I was connecting to a MySQL instance at the time.  Will have to try this again later.